# Am I using lxml the proper way to validate XML file for syntax errors?

Tags: python, xml, maven, pom.xml

I am trying use the below pom.xml to create a Python script and validate the pom for any syntax errors using `lxml` to further confirm the `<version>`is a `SNAPSHOT` and update the `<version>` to match this format `ci_{git hub org}_{branch name}-SNAPSHOT`.

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.wsi.devops</groupId>
  <artifactId>python-test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

This where I am currently with my solution,

```
# For XML validation, importing the etree module from the lxml 
# package, as well as sys for handling input.
from lxml import etree
import sys

#filename as command line arguments
filename_xml = sys.argv[1]

# parse xml
try:
    doc = etree.parse(sys.argv[1])
    print('XML well formed, syntax ok.')

# check for XML syntax errors
except etree.XMLSyntaxError as err:
    print('XML Syntax Error, see error_syntax.log')
    with open('error_syntax.log', 'w') as error_log_file:
        error_log_file.write(str(err.error_log))
    quit()

except:
    print('Unknown error, exiting.')
    quit()

#Update version
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
tree = et.parse(sys.argv[1])
tree.find('1.0').text = 'ci_{git hub org name}_{branch name}'
tree.write(sys.argv[1])
```

Just want to get some help for any mistakes I am committing in my script.

Comment: I corrected your indentation; I hope that was just a mistake entering it here and not the actual bug. Also, why are you reading the XML file as a string, then converting the string back into a file object to parse it with lxml? You do know you can just do `etree.parse(sys.argv[1])` right?

Comment: I do not know that, so no need of `StringIO` for this? And I am not required to do any `io` as well, which should rule out `sys` as well?

Comment: You still need *sys* to get `sys.argv`, but you don't need io or StringIO for this. I'm trying to help you but I'm having trouble understanding what the "update version" code does. What is *datafile* exactly?

Comment: I have simplified my code. The task is just is to validate `sys.argv[1]` for syntax errors and confirm the `<version>` is a `SNAPSHOT` before updating the `sys.argv[1]`'s `<version>` itself to further execute it in a docker container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is an incorrect use of the *ElementTree* *parse()* method. It takes a tagname or a certain simplified xpath syntax, whereas you seem to be treating it like the *str.find()* method which takes an arbitrary string. What you need is the *version* tag.

Your parsing code should look like this:

```
version = tree.find('ns:version', {ns:'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0'})
if 'SNAPSHOT' in version.text:
    version.text = 'ci_{git hub org name here}_{branch name here}'
    # I guess you have some other code that sets this version properly
else:
    print("Not a snapshot.")
```

Note that you always have to set a namespace to find *version*. That brings me to my second point; why are you parsing the file twice? *lxml* is just a more featureful version of *xml*. You only need to import one! *lxml* also has the advantage that its *ElementTrees* have an *nsmap* attribute, so you don't have to type the namespace yourself. I guess that makes it more robust, if Apache releases a new Maven version or something:

```
tree = etree.parse(sys.argv[1])
version = tree.find('ns:version', {'ns':tree.getroot().nsmap[None]})
```

For complete code, using only *lxml*:

```
from lxml import etree
import sys

# parse xml
try:
    tree = etree.parse(sys.argv[1])
    print('XML well formed, syntax ok.')

except OSError: # check for file errors (e.g missing)
    print("Bad file: " + sys.argv[1])
    quit()

# check for XML syntax errors
except etree.XMLSyntaxError as err:
    print('XML Syntax Error, see error_syntax.log')
    with open('error_syntax.log', 'w') as error_log_file:
        error_log_file.write(str(err.error_log))
    quit()

except:
    print('Unknown error, exiting.')
    quit()

#Update version
version = tree.find('ns:version', {'ns':tree.getroot().nsmap[None]})
if 'SNAPSHOT' not in version.text:
    print("Not a snapshot")
    quit() # Quitting after a failure is a way to avoid nesting
version.text = 'ci_{git hub org name}_{branch name}'
# I guess you have some other code that sets this version properly
tree.write(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Your complete code has a syntax error, I'm passing the pom.xml from the same directory where the script is located. It's saying `File "script.py", line 18 print("Bad file: " + sys.argv[1], file=sys.stderr) SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. I am wondering if you missed `file = sys.argv[1]`

Comment: Nope, that line looks (and runs) fine to me! *file* here has nothing to do with `sys.argv[1]`, it's a keyword argument to `print()` to get it to print to standard error instead of standard output; this is so you see the error message even if you pipe the output to a file (or to /dev/null). What python version are you using?

Comment: I see, and I'm using Python 2.7.15

Comment: OK, I tested with that. If you remove the keyword arguments (turn them into simple `print("string")` statements), it should work. That said, why aren't you using python3?

Comment: I've edited my code to avoid the offending backward-incompatible syntax (which didn't add anything to the example anyway)

Comment: That makes sense now, I'm still in python 2 and you know 2.7.15 is the latest in it. I still need to work towards python 3.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to write unit test/s to see if this code works instead of sending it for someone else to test if it is working?